# adding values for checkbox for php mailer

Tags: html, css, checkbox, phpmailer

I have a checkbox, I have turned into a male/female slider. 
Im confused how can I make a value for these in the HTML???
off=male on=female
I know I have to somehow turn unchecked into male and checked into female but how do I code this in the html? 
So when I make a mailer script I can email these values to me?

```
 $gender = $_POST['gender'] ;
<span style='font-size: px;'>Gender:$gender<br></span>
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #0024FF;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
   border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #FF1493;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}

/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/
.slider:after
{
 content:'Male';
 color: white;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked + .slider:after
{  
  content:'Female';/*ON*/
}

/*--------- END --------*/
```

```html
<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="togBtn"><div class="slider round"></div></label>
```

I have a checkbox, I have turned into a male/female slider. 
Im confused how can I make a value for these in the HTML???
off=male on=female
I know I have to somehow turn unchecked into male and checked into female but how do I code this in the html? 
So when I make a mailer script I can email these values to me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can access the value with JavaScipt:

```
var isFemale = document.getElementById("togBtn").checked;
var gender = "Male";
if(isFemale) {
     gender = "Female";
}
```

Or, since it looks like you are accepting the form data with php:

```
$gender = 'Male';
if(isset($_REQUEST['gender']) && $_REQUEST['gender'] === true) {
     $gender = 'Female';
}
```

For your reference, $_REQUEST is like a combination of $_POST and $_GET but $_POST would work in its place

Comment: I know theses a way to add values into <input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="togBtn">

Comment: It already has a value of true/false depending on whether it's checked, you should see this in your $_POST object as $_POST["gender"], my code is showing how to convert this to string "Male" or "Female".  What do you see when you do var_dump($_POST); in php?

Comment: I think what u have done is make it to where if a user slides it to female it will be checked and ur php would print that here in email using my code  <span style='font-size: px;'>Gender:$gender<br></span> right?

Comment: It sounds like you can throw out the Javascript part, that is only if you need to access the gender on the page itself.  The PHP code should get you all ready to email the gender using your code and $gender variable